# operator <= not defined on pointer

Tags: go, bigint

I can't seem to use the <= (**greater than or equal to**) operator when using big.Int.

Is there a way of comparing two big.Ints?

My code is as such:

```
for i := big.NewInt(2); i <= sqrt; i.Add(i, big.NewInt(1)) {...
```

'**i**' and '**sqrt**' are what I want to compare.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Use the [`Int.Cmp` method](https://godoc.org/math/big#Int.Cmp).

Answer (score 2):

Use the Cmp method of big (https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Cmp)
Cmp returns -1 if less than. 0 if equal or 1 if greater.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    for i := big.NewInt(2); i.Cmp(big.NewInt(10)) < 1; i.Add(i, big.NewInt(1)) {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

playground: https://play.golang.org/p/FpU8xaRrdE

Comment: How would I implement this as `<=`? As in, less than or equal to?

Comment: It is less than or equal to. Remember that Cmp returns 1 only if greater. So when I is 10, Cmp returns 0 and it still prints, but when i is 11 it returns 1 and stops. Take a good look at the playground example, modify it until you understand.